# A question about generating table

Tags: list-manipulation, syntax, formatting

Consider a vector that is generated somehow, say

```
vec:={RandomReal[{0,2}],RandomReal[{0,1}],RandomReal[{2,3}]};
```

Note that it is evaluated on-flight, I cannot prepare it preliminarily. (in reality, instead of `RandomReal`, there are some complicated functions). I can evaluate its separate components, but the total time of generation will be 3 times larger.

Next, I make the following table:

```
tab=Table[{RandomReal[{0,1}],vec},{i,1,10,1}];
```

The output looks as
[image]

Instead, I want the following output:
[image]

I may generate it using tedious code

```
tab2 = Table[{tab[[i]][[1]], tab[[i]][[2]][[1]], tab[[i]][[2]][[2]], 
  tab[[i]][[2]][[3]]}, {i, 1, Length[tab], 1}]
```

However, it requires time and looks ugly. Does anyone know how to generate `tab2` instead of `tab` using one command?

Comment: ``Flatten /@ tab``.

Comment: Why not simply `tab=Table[{RandomReal[{0,1}],RandomReal[{0,2}],RandomReal[{0,1}],RandomReal[{2,3}]},{i,1,10,1}];`

Comment: @yarchik : it is because in reality, instead of RandomReal, there are some complicated functions. Precisely, I first compute vector as a whole and only then may divide into components.

Comment: So you think to generate 3 numbers at a time and then another number is beautiful, but to generate all 4 of them at a time is ugly?

Comment: @yarchik : I cannot generate the 4 numbers separately.

Comment: `tab = Table[{RandomReal[{0, 1}], vec} // Flatten, {10}]`